# MVC URL Rewriting redirect with original name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller named HomeController, I am re-writing its all actions and even the name of controller,by decorating them with Route and Routeprefix respectively.
This is my controller with action method Index

```
 [RoutePrefix("MyPortal")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Home")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        }

    [Route("Index")]
        public ActionResult LandingPage()
        {
        }
     }
```

Its working fine,but when I type Home/Index in URL,its giving me error

```
A public action method 'index' was not found on controller 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'.    /Home/index
```

I want to redirect the user to Index ActionResult,if he type Home/Index or MyPortal/Home

Similarly, he should redirect to LandingPage, if he type Home/LandingPage or MyPortal/Index.

MyPortal/Home  or MyPortal/Index is working fine.

Comment: Why do you want the redirect? How could the user figure out by himself to type in 'Home/Index' if there isn't any link to it?
If you really want redirects, you can use the URL rewriting module (if hosted in IIS or IIS express).

Comment: I am just assuming if user type Home/Index then what should I do in this case?I am supposed to redirect to home page

Comment: A normal (non developer) user will not type in Home/Index. Most users only use the address bar to search for google (not even typing in google.com)
So I would worry about the redirect. What you can do, is set up a nice 404 Not Found page. You can find here on SO and packages on nuget.

Answer (score -1):

How about this one ..? But your last case (MyPortal/Index) will not work

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
[RoutePrefix("MyPortal")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Index")]
    [Route("Home")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
    [Route("LandingPage")]
    public ActionResult LandingPage()
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? That's not going to cause a redirect. Duplicate RoutePrefix attribute is not allowed. And you have Index on the 2 different actions.

Comment: Please stop guessing and actually test your anwser. If you found something that works, you can create a new anwser and leave this one here as an example of what doesn't work :-)

Comment: No,we cannot add multiple RoutePrefix attributes